# Connecting Java to SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite

I downloaded sqlitejdbc-v056.jar from

http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/

to `C:\test` folder in Windows XP 32-bit. And downloaded SQLite3 database in `C:\test` folder.
Then I ran `java -cp .:sqlitejdbc-v056.jar`. Then I tested after compiling `Test.java`, but it gave me this error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't find your compiled Test.class file. You need to include its location in your classpath. Is it supposed to be in the current directory? that seems to be where you intend it to be, since your path includes '.'.

I may be mis-remembering this, but, ':' is not the path separator on Windows if I recall correctly. It is on Linux, but think it's ';' on Windows? Then try "-cp .;sqlitejdbc-v056.jar". Might be wrong.

Comment: Thanks Sean .. problem solved as you said.
Now I've another error message, can you help pls?
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.Exception: no such table: Emp
the code is:
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");